# How to include each registered bundle's named assets into main assetic config?

Tags: angularjs, symfony, module, assetic

I'm building a single page app with AngularJS on front-end and Symfony 2 on the backend. I would like to make the app modular and keep Angular modules in sync with Symfony bundles.

For example, if I have `Articles` module in angular `angular.module('Articles', [])`, I probably would like to keep all `Articles` assets (js files for services, controllers & directives, CSS files, html partials) in `MyNamespace\ArticlesBundle` Resources folder.

Let's say I can use some features in AngularJS at run-time if corresponding Symfony bundles are registered in the kernel (let's ignore the fact there might be js errors for unresolved dependencies if some module depends on bundle that is not registered).

Is there a way to configure assetic from `MyNamespace\ArticlesBundle` so that it would add all required assets into main layout for this bundle if it is registered? Like having separate `assets.yml` in config for every bundle:

```
//MyNamespace/ArticlesBundle/Resources/config/assets.yml
assetic:
  assets:
    js:
      input:
        - '@ArticlesBundle/Resources/public/js/controllers.js'
        - '@ArticlesBundle/Resources/public/js/directives.js'
    css:
      input:
        - '@ArticlesBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css'
```

and merging it with `app/config/config.yml` assetic section? And then in layout it should output assets of all registered bundles:

```
{% javascripts '@js' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your need is covered by this bundle:

https://github.com/AppVentus/AsseticInjectorBundle

In each bundles you create, you can add a "Resources/config/assetic_injector.json" file, that define which asset to inject, and under which tag:

```
//ArticleBundle/Resources/config/assetic_injector.json
{
    "require_all":
    {
        "javascripts":
        {
            "angular":
            [
                "@ArticlesBundle/Resources/public/js/controllers.js",
                "@ArticlesBundle/Resources/public/js/directives.js"
            ]
        },
        "stylesheets":
        {
            "angular": "@ArticlesBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css"
        }
    }
}
```

You just have to add the filter "injector" on your "{% javascripts %}" and "{% javascripts %}" blocks and it's done.

```
{% javascripts injector="angular" %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}


{% stylesheets injector="angular" %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% stylesheets %}
```

If you have other bundles with angular assets dependency, you can easily create an assetic_injector.json file for them, and all assets under the "angular" tag will be automatically injected.